# Perform action on received SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

How to perform an action in android when sms is received?

below code is not working:

```
public class Sms extends BroadcastReceiver{
    AudioManager audioManager;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {


        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: need Permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>`

Comment: read this post http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android for sending SMS.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't perform any "action"... It just stops the text message from being handled (assuming you've defined the Receiver correctly in your manifest)

Comment: @IncrediApp, i have to chage silent mode to ringer mode when sms is receivet.. wht i have  require to do that.. is above code sufficient.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".Sms">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Note the priority - This will allow this receiver to be (one of the) first handling the received text messages